# Почему username принимает значение None при отправке post запроса с указанным значением val

Tags: python, flask

Usernmae должен принимать значение, узаканное в post запросе. Вместо этого получаю None. Как исправить?[image]

Comment: потому что вы пытаетесь получить свой параметр из get-запроса, а у вас post-запрос. И замените свой скриншот на код текстом.

Comment: из документации: Для доступа к параметрам, представленным в URL (?ключ=значение), вы можете использовать атрибут args

Comment: из той же документации: Для доступа к данным формы (данным, которые передаются в запросах типа POST или PUT), вы можете использовать атрибут form.
https://flask-russian-docs.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/quickstart.html